# JsonPath (JayWay) that returns only specific keys for objects in a JSON array that have those keys

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jayway

Objective:

- I have a JSON with an array of JSON objects.
- I want to return only array objects that have certain members (string:element) with particular strings.
- Of those filtered objects in the array, I want to return only the filtered strings, not the whole object.
- All tests are being made at https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com.

I have advanced a bit, after this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265388/extract-several-json-objects-at-different-depths-with-jayway-jsonpath) was solved.

Consider the following JSON

```
[  
   {  
      "A":"val1",
      "B":"val2",
      "C":"val3",
      "D":{  
         "E":[  
            {  
               "F":"val4"
            }
         ],
         "G":[  
            {  
               "H":"val5",
               "I":"val6",
               "J":"val7"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "A":"val8",
      "B":"val9",
      "C":"val10",
      "D":{  
         "E":[  
            {  
               "F":"val11"
            }
         ],
         "G":[  
            {  
               "H":"val12",
               "I":"val13",
               "J":"val14"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "A":"val15",
      "B":"val16"
   },
   {  
      "A":"val8",
      "B":"val9",
      "C":"val10",
      "D":{  
         "E":[  
            {  
               "F":"val11"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

On a JsonPath (Java JayWay) parser, the following path:
`[?(@.B && @.C && @.D.G)]['B','C','D']`

returns:
 - only objects that have B, C and D.G.
 - for each object, it returns only B, C and D.

```
[
   {
      "B" : "val2",
      "C" : "val3",
      "D" : {
         "E" : [
            {
               "F" : "val4"
            }
         ],
         "G" : [
            {
               "H" : "val5",
               "I" : "val6",
               "J" : "val7"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "B" : "val9",
      "C" : "val10",
      "D" : {
         "E" : [
            {
               "F" : "val11"
            }
         ],
         "G" : [
            {
               "H" : "val12",
               "I" : "val13",
               "J" : "val14"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

What is missing:

- This solution still returns E (D.E), and has G nested.
- Ideally, I would like to return only:

  - B, C, and G.  or
  - B, C and D.G.

thanks